# Is there a pandas method that achieves the same thing as df.groupby(column_list).size().reset_index()?

Tags: python, pandas

When working with pandas dfs, I often find myself wanting to extract a set of values from a given list of columns like so:

```
>>> df
number   city       date
1        Denver     2019-01-14
1        Denver     2019-01-15
1        Denver     2019-01-15
2        Seattle    2019-03-22
2        Seattle    2019-03-22
```

the sets would be like

```
>>> df_sets
number   city        date
1        Denver_1     2019-01-14
1        Denver_1     2019-01-15
2        Seattle      2019-03-22
```

I know you can achieve this by doing

```
df.groupby(['number', 'city', 'date']).size().reset_index().drop(0, axis=1)
```

but I'm wondering if there is a single method for this (the stuff after groupby())

Comment: `df.drop_duplicates(['number', 'city', 'date'])`

Comment: It would be nice if there was a parameter to keep only the the specified columns, but I guess putting the specific columns into a list would be simple enough. The following line would just include `df = df[column_list]]`

Comment: `df[['number', 'city', 'date']].drop_duplicates()` ?

Comment: You can still use your method for this, but then bit easier: `df.groupby(['number', 'city', 'date']).first().reset_index()`

Comment: @Brendan ah, thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use just `df.drop_duplicates()`, without column list (*subset*).

This way you don't set any subset, so the uniqueness of a row is checked
on all columns.

If you want to perform such an operation on a subset of columns, you can
write:

```
df[<column_list>].drop_duplicates()
```

i.e. you take only your subset of columns and then apply *drop_duplicates*
to them.